# ListView Showing duplicate items when scrolled beyond visible part of screen

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My problem is really crazy. I have a ListView and a custom adapter. Now in the custom adapter, I have two groups of items inside a ViewAnimator, the first group only contains a button(a three dot "more" button) while the second group contains "info", "delete", and "share" buttons. I call them buttons but they're actually clickable ImageViews. The "more" button is the default visisbe item. When the "more button is clicked, the view animator shows the second group.

Now the crazy thing that happens is that while the second group is visible on a particular list item, if you scroll down the list beyond a portion that was visible when the second group was shown for that list item, some random list items automatically show the second group.(instead of waiting for the more button to be clicked) 
Note that this only affects the ViewAnimator items. The textviews in the lists are all correct. The ViewAnimator is somehow automatically activated.
Any sort of help is greatly appreciated.

Below is my custom adapter class.

```
package model;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.ViewAnimator;

import com.app.myapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class CustomListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<UserItem> {

private int layoutResource;
private Activity activity;
private ArrayList<UserItem> userItemsList = new ArrayList<>();

public CustomListviewAdapter(Activity act, int resource, ArrayList<UserItem> data) {
    super(act, resource, data);
    layoutResource = resource;
    activity = act;
    userItemsList = data;
    notifyDataSetChanged();

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return userItemsList.size();
}

@Override
public UserItem getItem(int position) {
    return userItemsList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getPosition(UserItem item) {
    return super.getPosition(item);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return super.getItemId(position);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;

    if ( row == null || (row.getTag() == null)) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.userNameText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
        holder.userAddressText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userAddressText);
        holder.infoButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
        holder.shareButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        holder.deleteButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        holder.moreButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
        holder.moreAnimator = (ViewAnimator) row.findViewById(R.id.moreAnimator);



        row.setTag(holder);

    }else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();


    }


    holder.userItem = getItem(position);

    holder.userNameText.setText(holder.userItem.getUserName());
    holder.userAddressText.setText(holder.userItem.getUserAddress());

    final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
    holder.moreButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finalHolder.moreAnimator.showNext();


        }
    });

    holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //Do Something

        }
    });
    holder.shareButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //Do Something

        }
    });
    holder.infoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //Do Something
        }
    });



    return row;

}

public class ViewHolder {
    UserItem userItem;
    TextView userNameText;
    TextView userAddressText;
    ImageView infoButton;
    ImageView deleteButton;
    ImageView shareButton;
    ImageView moreButton;
    ViewAnimator moreAnimator;



}

}
```

Comment: you mean you have two type of list item...?

Answer (score 0):

Make your position variable final.

```
@Override 
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
......
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this does not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is because rows recycle views for efficiency, so one common problem is to define what happens when you do an action and assume that the starting point will always be the same (which is not).

So in your case, once you click on a view and `finalHolder.moreAnimator.showNext();` is called, it will be also called when this row gets reused.

What you can do to avoid it is to set the starting point for all rows, I don't know ViewAnimator but something in the line of `finalHolder.moreAnimator.showPrevious();` inside getView().

Comment: I don't know how to implement this. The finalHolder.moreAnimator is not visible inside getView()

Comment: Yes you can use `holder.moreAnimator` in getView(), right after setting the userName and userAddress for example. Try adding something like this:<br/> `if (holder.moreAnimator.getDisplayedChild() > 0) { holder.moreAnimator.showPrevious(); }`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 static class ViewHolder {

    UserItem userItem;
    TextView userNameText;
    TextView userAddressText;
    ImageView infoButton;
    ImageView deleteButton;
    ImageView shareButton;
    ImageView moreButton;
    ViewAnimator moreAnimator;

    public ViewHolder(View row) {


        userNameText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userNameText);
        userAddressText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.userAddressText);
        infoButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.infoButton);
        shareButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.shareButton);
        deleteButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
        moreButton = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.moreButton);
        moreAnimator = (ViewAnimator) row.findViewById(R.id.moreAnimator);
    }
}
```

in getView

```
  @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResource, parent,
                false);
    }

    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it's also not working. It introduced lots of errors. I tried to understand and fix them but I got lost at some point.